Has this random process been studied on grid graphs?
As an offshoot of a different discussion I got curious about (uniform) random spanning trees on grid graphs (torus graphs in particular, to avoid having to think about edge effects) and what their diameters (that is, the longest path through the tree) would look like. Perhaps unsurprisingly, the effect looks much like a random walk:

Some rough computation on graphs up to size 320 suggests that the average length of the longest path on an $n\times n$ torus is of order $n^C$ for $C\approx 1.26$; it seems clearly larger than $5/4$, but resemblance to the fractal dimension $\ln(4)/\ln(3)\approx 1.26$ of the Sierpinski gasket feels a little like numerology.
I was able to find a little research on the expected diameter of random spanning trees for some graphs, particularly this article from Chung, Horn, and Lu; unfortunately, their results depend on a degree that increases with $n$ and don't seem to apply to the fixed-degree case.
This is such a natural question that it feels like it should have come up before, in a context of random walks or percolation theory or similar; does anyone know of any references or information on this particular question?

What algorithms are you using to generate the random spanning tree and then find the longest path?

@JairTaylor The random spanning tree is being generated by the random walk first-visit approach; see e.g. the first paragraph of https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15859n/RelatedWork/RandomTrees-Wilson.pdf . The longest-path algorithm is traditional and I'm not sure who to ascribe it to: from any node of the tree, choose a node that's furthest from that one; then choose a node that's furthest from the first node chosen. Those two nodes will have the longest path between them.

(There is a physical realization of the latter algorithm that sticks in my head: grab your graph by a node, shake it, and then grab one of the bottom nodes. lift that one up, shake it, and grab one of the now-bottom nodes; you're holding a diameter.)

I've now asked this question on MO as well: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/470694/has-this-random-process-been-studied-on-grid-graphs
